# Error on setting Environment variables in Google Cloud using the SDK

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I am trying to set up Environment Variables for my Django app on Google Cloud.
I entered the following on the SDK:

```
gcloud functions deploy env_vars --runtime python37 --set-env-vars SUBSCRIPTION_KEY=1234567890 --trigger-http
```

The error returned was:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: {"error": {"canonicalCode": "INTERNAL", "errorMessage": "`pip_install_from_wheels` had stderr output:\n/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7: No module named pip\n\nerror: `pip_install_from_wheels` returned code: 1", "errorType": "InternalError", "errorId": "ECB5F712"}}
```

Please help.

My `requirements.txt` file:

```
Django==2.2.5
Pillow==6.2.1
azure-cognitiveservices-language-textanalytics==0.2.0
azure-cognitiveservices-nspkg==3.0.1
azure-cognitiveservices-search-newssearch==1.0.0 
azure-cognitiveservices-search-nspkg==3.0.1
azure-common==1.1.23
azure-nspkg==3.0.2
msrest==0.6.10
numpy==1.17.1
oauthlib==3.1.0
pandas==0.24.2
pandas-datareader==0.7.4
pip==19.0.3
requests==2.21.0
setuptools==40.8.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
statistics==1.0.3.5
ta==0.4.5
gunicorn==20.0.4
```

Comment: Could you provide more information, like the requirements.txt?

Comment: is your function name called env_vars ? weird. In seems you are missing a module from the error message though

Comment: requirements.txt added

Comment: any chance you can get into the instance that's being deployed as the script user and check its paths? pip comes installed by default since Python 3.4, but it looks like maybe it's not in the path of the user running that script?

Comment: Looks like error is in function code, please provide more detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `pip` in your `requirements.txt`, possibly because you did something like `pip freeze --all > requirements.txt`. The Python 3.7 runtime for Cloud Functions has a bug where specifying `pip` as a dependency for the function causes this issue.

You should remove `pip` from your `requirements.txt` file, but also make sure that you're only specifying the requirements that are actually dependencies for your function.