# Cloud Function Build Failed

Tags: function, google-cloud-platform, pip, cloud

I just changed two lines of code in the Google cloud functions source code using inline statement, the two lines of code involve parsing date string using datetime library, no updates to anything else. This same deployment has been working for more than a year now.

All of a sudden I get two errors -

Error 1 -

> (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build
>   failed: {"error": {"canonicalCode": "INTERNAL", "errorMessage":
>   "`pip_install_from_wheels` had stderr
>   output:\n/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7: No module named pip\n\nerror:
>   `pip_install_from_wheels` returned code: 1", "errorType":
>   "InternalError", "errorId": "ECB5F712"}}

**Resolved that by removing pip from requirements.txt (again not sure why this is a problem now and not for over a year)**

If I address 1, I get the following error -

Error 2 -

> (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build
>   failed: {"error": {"canonicalCode": "INTERNAL", "errorMessage":
>   "gzip_tar_runtime_package gzip /tmp/tmpGLHQx9.tar -1\nexited with
>   error [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory\ngzip_tar_runtime_package is
>   likely not on the path", "errorType": "InternalError", "errorId":
>   "2A1581FF"}}

Memory is already at 2048 and nothing changed other than the two lines of code above.

Let me know if this has been happening and what is the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this has to do with packages than anything else.  I deployed a dummy function and added each package from requirements.txt until it failed. It turns out the problem packages were

- a. gpflow
- b. tensorflow

Last deployment with these packages was successful as of Feb 20. Not sure why I can't install them without those errors anymore. regardless, tried using the versions that would have been consistent with Feb 20 timeline with no luck. So refactored my code and removed all the functionality that was using that and deployed successfully.

Request to Google Cloud Folks : Why this behavior ? Also "Invalid ARGUMENT" in logs (Stackdriver or google cloud logging whatever you call it) is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

The first error, as explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59586281), is due to `pip` being defined in your `requirements.txt` file. Specifying `pip` as a dependency for the function causes message to appear. You did the right thing by removing it from the `requirements.txt` file.

The second error usually appears if the number of files or the size of the content that is being uploaded is too big and the instance used to deploy your code runs out of memory. You perhaps were using too many dependencies or static files, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60872411).